# Перенесена дата?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Можно ли "переносить" дату? Ведь по определению "Дата - это запись, включающая в себя число месяца, месяц и год" (Википедия). По-моему, можно выбрать другую дату, в крайнем случае, изменить дату (поскольку дата - это запись), но не "перенести" дату. Однако примеров с "перенесением" даты - бесчисленное количество. Вот один из них: "Перенесена дата запуска «Протона-М» с американским спутником" (сайт "Известий")

Answer (score 2):

Определение определению рознь. Дата - не просто принадлежность календаря или регламентированная *форма записи* произвольного числа месяца при годе. Это прежде всего указание (с точностью до дня) **времени события**, назначенного на будущее или произошедшего. Например, дата отправки груза, дата изготовления товара, дата подписания документа и пр. Нет события - нет даты. В этом смысле назначенный на *будущее* день (приписанную дату) можно переносить с одного числа на другое и т. п. - она лишь "накладывается" на календарь.

Comment: Ээээ.... ***День** переносить с одного числа на другое?!* Что-то тут не так у Вас. Хорошо, если только неудачная формулировка, но если за ней стоит реальное недоразумение, то никак не могу принять.

Comment: Вы никогда не сталкивались с переносом выходного дня (дня отъезда в командировку, дня свадьбы...) с одного числа на другое?

Comment: "Выходного" сталкивалась. Просто "дня" - нет.  У "выходного" переносится именно выходной. Причем обычно именно на другой день, а не на другое число. Хотя и это не лучший стиль. Но не в этом дело. У вас идет игра на терминах день и число, а это синонимы в данном случае. Поэтому и объяснение неубедительное.

Comment: Это не синонимы: "день отъезда" означает привязку дня к событию (это содержательное наполнение "дня"), а "число", на которое его можно назначить или переназначить - привязку дня ко времени (это календарное понимание "дня"). В приведенном контексте "назначенный день" - не "просто день" (календарный или какой-то ещё), а день, на которое назначается событие. Назначить или перенести дату - значит так или иначе разместить день этого события (напр. день отъезда) на оси времени.

Comment: @Alex_ander, как выясняется из вашего примера, вопрос касается не только дат. По-моему, также нельзя говорить о переносе координаты объекта, а правильно говорить о переносе объекта (или изменении его координат). Т.е. не день размещать на оси дней, а событие.

Comment: "День" - это докалендарное понятие. Вспомним забытый экологический триллер, в прокате называвшийся "День, когда всплыла рыба" - здесь точно не имеет значения, когда это случилось по календарю или при какой луне. Трудности в понимании "переноса" даты связаны с отождествлением всех аспектов "дня" с одним только календарным.

Comment: Что касается "даты", вот более простая аналогия: на календаре пронумерованы все дни месяца соотв. года, но это  - не даты. **Датами** становятся лишь ваши пометки в календаре при некоторых числах: вы назначаете или переносите в календаре _даты событий_ и можете выписать их в численной форме после того, как сами установили соответствие между событием и числом. Сами же можете и перенести дату.

Comment: @Alex_ander, ваша трактовка даты как пометки не соответствует ни одному известному мне определению даты. По-моему, дата - это координата события на оси времени, а не метка, которой вы эту координату выделили.

Comment: Правильно понимаете как _координату события_, а не как числовое деление оси времени. Если речь идёт о планируемом событии, то эту самую координату можно "переносить" вдоль оси. Авторы статьи в википедии интересовались только формой записи, поэтому в их определении случилось отождествление самого понятия с формой записи соответствующего ему числа. Что касается выражения "изменение даты", то это больше подходит к случаям исправления (записи) и даже подлога :)

Comment: Координата - это и есть число (1.матем., геогр. число, определяющее положение точки в системе координат - Викисловарь)

Comment: Вот пример изменения даты: "в связи с погодными условиями организаторы оставляют за собой право изменить дату и место проведения соревнований"

Comment: Да, это число, но только то, которое соответствует конкретной точке - если только она нанесена на график. "Изменение даты" - тоже возможная, хотя и более формальная фразеология (мы сейчас написали одно, а понадобится - там же напишем другое, мол, цифры в графе мероприятия изменим). Это не ошибка. Обратите внимание: "дата проведения соревнований" - не существует абстрактных "дат календаря"; даты переносить можно  с одного числа на другое, а числа календаря или разметку оси времени изменять по своему усмотрению - нет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46418/discussion-between---and-alex-ander).

Answer (score 0):

Переносить дату можно. Это не просто

> по определению дата - это запись, включающая в себя число месяца,
>   месяц и год

(Где вы вообще такое определение нашли?) это

> ДАТА, -ы; ж. [франц. date] Точное календарное время какого-л. события.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0&all=x

Против переноса **времени** (события) вы не возражаете?

*Кстати, понятие "даты" не исключает и времени суток, это тоже входит в понятие "календарное время", просто обычно говорят о "дате" и "времени"* дабы избежать разночтений.

Объяснений Alex_ander'а не совсем поняла. Его вывод никак не следуют из его утверждений. Поэтому бросила свои пять копеек. Вопрос-то был в том, иможно ли переносить дату, а не событие на другую дату с последним вопросов не возникает. И уж тем более - не "день" на другое число - вот тут как раз сомнительно.

Comment: (1) Определение даты нашел в Википедии (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0), но и ваше определение не меняет сути дела  

 (2) По-моему, событие может быть пeренесено, а время - нет. Перенести событие на другое время можно, а перенести время события (куда?) (на другое время?) – бессмысленность (перенести время на время).

Comment: Никакой бессмысленности, обычная метонимия. Съесть три тарелки можно? Вот и время можно перенести.

Comment: Не убеждает. Метонимия - это, грубо говоря, замещение. "Съесть три тарелки"  замещает "Съесть то, что наполняло три тарелки". А "перенести время" - замещает что? В моем примере, "Перенесена дата запуска" - замещает что?

Comment: @М_Г Вы правильно понимаете, вопрос в том можно ли переносить "дату"  или только событие на другую дату. Второе, конечно, гораздо точнее с формальной точки зрения, но не исключает (на мой взгляд) и первого, в живой особенно речи, ради чего я и привела свои рассуждения. . Что касается метонимии, то это выдумка Niemand'а. Он или значения термина не понимает, или неверно трактует ваш вопрос. Разбираться, что именно, нет никакого желания.

Comment: @М_Г По сути же вопроса "переноса *времени*" на "другое время" я все в ответе написала. Это разные времена. Сравните с Новым годом, например. Это ведь время.Но его можно "перенести" на другое время. Две шкалы, если угодно. И точка на одной шкале времени сопоставляется точке на другой шкале.